# Converting XSD to ECore

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I am currently trying to convert an XML Schema to ECore with the Eclipse Modeling Framework. EMF offers the attributre ecore:reference to indicate that an attribute should be translated into an EReference. However, this only works if the attribute is of type IDREF or anyURI. My problem is that any ID referenced via IDREF has to be unique througout the whole XML document. However, my XML has the following structure:

```
<A id="a1">
<B id="b1">
<ref idref="b2" />
</B>
<B id="b2">
<ref idref="b1" />
</B>
</A>

<A id="a2">
<B id="b1">
<ref idref="b2" />
</B>    
<B id="b2">
<ref idref="b1" />
</B>
</A>
```

The ids of the B-elelemts are only unique inside the sourrounding A-element. Thus the parser will throw an error if i declare the ids of the B-elements as type ID.

How can I tell EMF that idref is a reference to the attribute id of B-element which belongs to the same A-element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the XML Schema is really using ID and IDREF, then the instance you show isn't valid with respect to that schema.  Isn't that a problem?  It's more like a key/keyref, which isn't supported by Ecore either.

If it just comes down to wanting an Ecore model that can read and write such instances I would define an attribute `idref` that's just a string and define a transient reference `resolvedRef` of type A and I'd modify the getters and setters so that each derives sensibly from the other.  I.e., when you call `getResolvedRef`, it would check if the field for that is null, and if the field for the `idref` has a value, it would walk the model to resolve (look up that name in the appropriate scope) and store it in the field.

It's a bit tricky to define the mutual derivation in a sensible way for both getters and both setters, but it should be possible.

Comment: Your are completely right. In fact, I am using key/keyref in my schema. I just tried ID/IDREF to see what EMF will generate. But what I really need is key/keyref. I have already read about transient references. Can you explain what they are? If I understand you correctly my only solution is editing the generated code manually. Is this right?

Comment: A transient reference is just a reference that won't be serialized by the XML serializer. Yes, the solution would be to specialize the generated code for the two setters and getters. Some tricky things you would want to have work will are things like if you've resolved the reference and change the name (id) of the thing being referenced, would you want that new name serialized automatically? The simplest approach you could try is a transient reference with changeable false, so there's only a getter for it, no setter, and you can put all your logic for resolving the idref in that method.